# How to count characters in a table column?

Tags: r, database, string

So I am trying to count the number of characters in each word. I have a .db file. with 5 variables and one has 100 sets of words. Here is my code

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)

texts <- dbReadTable(con, "Document")
char <- texts %>% select(words)
str_count(char)
```

But my output is "argument is not an atomic vector; coercing[1] 563"
so the total number of 563 characters but what I want is a list/column were like word 1 has 4 characters, word 2 has 7, word 3 has 2... etc. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is because `select` returns a `data.frame` or `tbl_df`, whereas you are expecting it to be a vector. Try `pull(texts, words)`, or if you must have the pipe, then `texts %>% pull(words)` or just the boring-old `texts$words`. Or, as Konrad suggested, `str_count(texts$words)` or even just `nchar(texts$words)` (base R).

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, `str_count` expects a *character vector*. You’re passing it a `data.frame`.

To fix this, pass it the `words` column of `char`:

```
str_count(char$words)
```

Or, more likely, you want to modify your table and add a column with the counts:

```
char <- texts %>%
    select(words) %>%
    mutate(length = str_count(words))
```